# How to read a downdown values in an Excel using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a excel file where one column has a dropdown values.I am using PhpExcel so i need to read the dropdown values from it.How can this be achieved.

when i am reading the rows as

```
$rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
```

I m just getting the text when i dump the row i need the dropdown values too.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you need all the values from a cell dropdown, not simply the selected value, then you have to read the dropdown itself. This is a datavalidation object.

Assuming that the dropdown is in cell B1:

```
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('B1')
    ->getDataValidation();
```

will return the data validation object

You can then read the rules for that data validation using methods like `getType()`, `getOperator()`, `getFormula1()` and `getFormula2()`.... note that not all data validations are dropdowns; you'd be looking for a type of `PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST` for a dropdown list. You might also need to use the calculation engine to evaluate the formula used to build the list if it was derived from data elsewhere in the spreadsheet.

---

Alternatively, because it's unclear from your question, it could be a autofilter dropdown that you're asking about. You can retrieve the autofilter object for a worksheet using:

```
$autoFilter = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getAutoFilter();
```

Again, there are a series of methods for accessing the filter rules for each column.

```
$autoFilter->getColumn('C');
```

Will return the autofilter rules for column `C`, with methods like `getFilterType()` and `getRules()` providing the rule definitions for that autofilter.

The autofilter examples like `10autofilter-selection-display.php` show how to define autofilters; but there is also a useful `showHideRows()` method that can be used  the filter to hide/display the rows that match those rules

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I cant still extract the values from the dropdown getType(), getOperator(), getFormula1(),getFormula2(),getShowDropDown() nad etc but all of this is not focussing on the data i require is there a direct way of getting hold of the values in the dropdown.

Comment: Assuming that it's an autofilter that you're trying to read (you still haven't clarified that), I'm sorry that MS Excel doesn't provide that for you, because it's dynamically built at run-time, based on the filters that are currently applied.... If you apply your filters using the showHideRules, you can iterate over the rows looking at whether they are hidden or not, and using that information to build a list of values